# Two different outputs from terminal and web inspector. Incorrect view rendered

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I am having trouble with generating my views with `reactjs`. I have these two views which I would like to generate.

```
var test1 = (
    <div id="container">
      <p>{initials}</p>
      <p>loggedin!</p>
    </div>
    );

var test2 = (
    <div id="container">
      <p>notloggedin</p>
    </div>
    );


var initials = "";
var isLoggedIn = false;

var Layout = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function() {
        try {
            if (window && window.User) {
                initials = window.User.name.first[0].toUpperCase() + window.User.name.last[0].toUpperCase();
                isLoggedIn = true;
            }
        } catch(e) {
            // ignore
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            console.log(window.User);
            console.log(initials);
            return test1;
        } else {
            console.log("not logged in");
            return test2;
        }
    }
});
```

When I run this code, I have 2 different outputs from my terminal and my web inspector.

Terminal:

```
[1] rendering server side react /
[1] not logged in
```

Web inspector:

```
Object {username: "bli1", userId: "1298085750", address: "127.0.0.1", name: Object, email: "Bradford_Li@gmail.com"…}

BL
```

The first and second output from `console.log(window.User)` and `console.log(initials)` are displayed above. I am not sure why this is occurring. I'm not sure how to handle this to achieve the desired logic.

The view displayed on my broswer is that of `test2`

What I see on my browser is initially:

`notloggedin`

Then changes to

`loggedin!`

The `{initials}` object is not displayed on the browser. All that appears is whitespace on top of the text `loggedin!`

Comment: What engine are you running the terminal instance in? PhantomJS?

Comment: @JDavidSmith node.js

Comment: is the intended behavior that neither is logged in or that both are logged in? Node.js has no window object, so it will never show logged in.

Comment: @JDavidSmith sorry Hapijs on top of nodejs. The intended logic is to be either logged in or logged out.

Comment: in this particular example, should the result be logged in? because again -- even with hapijs -- there is no window object in node.js, so checking `window && window.User` will always return `false` so given the code sample you posted, the node instance will *never* indicate the user is logged in.

Comment: @JDavidSmith I guess I dont have a solid sense of the workflow. When I run this code, the terminal displays "not logged in". The browser displays "notloggedin" for a brief moment then displays "loggedin!". When you mentioned that window does not exist, it makes sense that for a brief moment "notloggedin" is displayed and also my terminal displays "not logged in". However `{initials}` is not displayed on the page when `loggedin!` is displayed. I dont understand why the web inspector, `window.User` object is printed and `initials` is printed. Could you explain to me why this is occurring?